# Joining tables in EF Core Linq Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, linq-query-syntax

I'm currently trying to make a Web Api with EF Core, and i'm running into some problems joining the tables i've got together. I'm working with the following Database Diagram:
[image]

And the data i'm currently getting back from my API looks this this:

```
[  
   {  
      "postId":1,
      "postDate":"2018-10-21T21:56:43.9838536",
      "content":"First entry in posts!",
      "user":{  
         "userId":1,
         "creationDate":"2018-10-21T21:56:36.3539549",
         "name":"Hansel"
      },
      "comments":[  
         {  
            "commentId":1,
            "postDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "content":"Nice!",
            "user":null
         },
         {  
            "commentId":2,
            "postDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "content":"Cool, here's another comment",
            "user":null
         },
         {  
            "commentId":3,
            "postDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "content":"and the last one for the night",
            "user":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "postId":2,
      "postDate":"2018-10-22T21:56:44.0650102",
      "content":"Its good to see that its working!",
      "user":{  
         "userId":2,
         "creationDate":"2018-10-16T21:56:36.4585213",
         "name":"Chris"
      },
      "comments":[  

      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see, its aalmost working, my issue here is the null values in the comments, i want to be able to get the users out as well. But for some reason i cant.

my current query looks like this (i'm using DTO's to clean up the JSON generated):

```
var result = from post in context.Posts
                join user in context.Users 
                on post.User.UserId equals user.UserId
                join comment in context.Comments                            
                on post.PostId equals comment.Post.PostId into comments
                select new PostDTO
                {
                    Content = post.Content,
                    PostDate = post.PostDate,
                    User = UserDTO.UserToDTO(user),
                    Comments = CommentDTO.CommentToDTO(comments.ToList()),
                    PostId = post.PostId
                };
```

If i was working with SQL i'd join the users onto 'comments', but i cant, so i've tried a similar-ish solution, which i thought would work.

```
var result = from post in context.Posts
                join user in context.Users on post.User.UserId equals user.UserId
                join comment in 
                    (from u in context.Users
                    join c in context.Comments
                    on u.UserId equals c.User.UserId select c)
                on post.PostId equals comment.Post.PostId into comments
                select new PostDTO
                {
                    Content = post.Content,
                    PostDate = post.PostDate,
                    User = UserDTO.UserToDTO(user),
                    Comments = CommentDTO.CommentToDTO(comments.ToList()),
                    PostId = post.PostId
                };
```

However, while this query does execute the results are the same as the first query i wrote, the issue being that user isnt joined onto comment

**TLDR; I can join User to post, and comment to post, but i cant bind user to comment**

I hope you will be able to help me, thanks in advance :)

Edit: Here's my models

```
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }
}

  public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't `join`, use navigation properties. And use AutoMapper, so you can project the entity classes to DTO classes in one line of code. The current code triggers client-side evaluation, because `CommentDTO.CommentToDTO()` can't be translated into SQL.

Comment: Can you post the models? As @Gert mentioned, you should really use navigation properties. The strange thing is that you seem to have them, but use them for joining. But `user` variable here `join user in context.Users on post.User.UserId equals user.UserId` is the same as `post.User`. If we continue, `post` should have `ICollecton<Comment> Comments` and `Comment` should have `User User`, so you should really be able to produce the result with just `select`s (projections).

Comment: I've posted the models now. 

I've got navigation properties, yes, but i'm unsure about how to utilize them properly as i havnt been able to find any examples that have a similar database structure as mine, i've tried to make a query with includes only and it gives me waaay too much data. example:
post + the comments + the comments users + the users comments and the users posts.

Comment: @GertArnold I've seen the AutoMapper suggestion a lot, and if i were doing a professional job i'd probably use it as its faster than doing it manually. But i'm doing it for fun and because i want to learn how this stuff works :) Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: AutoMapper is  fun too :) But I get your point. Happy coding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the posts with comments (and every comment's user) and post users, simply use `.Include()`

```
var res = this._dbContext.Posts
        .Include(p => p.User)
        .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.User)
        .ToList();
```

[image]

<del>If you don't like to introduce a 3rd party lib such as `AutoMapper`, you can create a `convertPostToDto` function and use .</del>

<del>res.Select(p => convertPostToDto(p))</del>

<del>to convert the `res` to the result</del>

Comment: Holy shit, i didnt even think about doing it that way, now i feel like a very stupid person.

I'll try it out and see if it works for me :)

Comment: All good except the last advice. Never create *function* and use it like suggested - it would cause client evaluation which should be avoided.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that it's possible to convert posts to dto on database.  I'll try that later, if I can confirm all the conversion can be done on database, I'll update my anwser.

Comment: Well, not really in the database, but when materializing the query result (it comes as `DbDataReader` and needs to be converted to objects). But using discoverable projections allows EF to create the necessary SQL `SELECT`s and avoid creation (and tracking) intermediate entity objects. Basically the difference between AutoMapper `Map` and `ProjectTo` :) Anyway, you are welcome.

Comment: I was making a join query, and then I saw `.Include()`. Life saver :) @IvanStoev